# Can you run gsutil in Google Cloud Workflows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-workflows

Looking for an easy way to run gsutil command line arguments in Google Cloud Workflows.

The specific problem I'm trying to solve is dynamically remove all objects in a Cloud Storage Bucket so that the bucket can then be deleted. Trying to do this as part of a Workflows project. gsutil can remove files with this command `gsutil rm -a gs://bucket/**` and if I could run that in a Workflows step that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Workflow call only API. So, you have to call API, as gsutil do. I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886) to list all the file and to call a "compose" operation on the file. You can customize the code to call the delete API

---

If you really want to use GSUTIL, you can use [Cloud Run Job](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs) for instance. And execute it with an API call with Workflows

Comment: Thank you. For the article and the possible work-a-round if I really want to use GSUTIl through Cloud Run.